# What's the meaning of 'Polypropylene ear right/left'

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of *'Polypropylene ear right/left'*?

Polypropylene is a kind of material.

What does **ear right, ear left** mean?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Next time it might be useful if you could provide a bit more context.

Comment: Out of context, it means nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site. Best guess given lack of context is that this is is form an audiologist's order or a hearing assist device. Polypropylene is the material from which the exterior of the device is to be made, and ear right / left is for the audiologist to specify whether the device is for use in the right or left ear.

Comment: I work in the field of polymers—"ear right/left" definitely has no connection to the materials themselves. So this seems as likely an explanation as any.